# How do you change an HTML tag with certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django-models

I'm trying to make an e-commerce site with Django and I'm stuck at my home page not being able to display which products are already in my cart. I am pretty sure I haven't got the JavaScript right but I'm an absolute beginner to web-dev so could also be the Python.

This is my home :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for pett in pets.all %}
<div class="row pt-3" onfocus="func(pett)">
    <div class="col-8" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' pett.id %}';" style="cursor: pointer">
      <h2>{{ pett.name }}</h2>
      <h4>{{ pett.breed }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <a id="link{{pett.id}}" href= "javascript:{document.getElementById('add{{pett.id}}').submit()}"><button id="button{{pett.id}}" class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'><h1>Add to cart +</h1></button></a>
        </div>
  </div>
  <form id="add{{pett.id}}" method="POST" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' pett.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden"/>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(pett){
  if(cart.objects.filter(pet=pett).count()>0) {
    document.getElementById('button{{pett.id}}').innerHTML = "Added ✔︎";
    document.getElementById('link{{pett.id}}').href = "";}
                  }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the call to my home method :

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    pets = Pet.objects
    if request.user :
        cart = Cart.objects.get(buyer=request.user)
    else:
        cart=NULL
    return render(request,'pets/home.html',{'pets':pets,'cart':cart})
```

This is my cart model :

```
from django.db import models


class Cart(models.Model):
    buyer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    pet = models.ManyToManyField('pets.Pet')
```

Everything else is working perfectly.

Comment: If you are not using AJAX when the user adds a new item but instead you are reloading the whole page -> then you don't need JS to display which items are in the cart. You can use Django templating logic to set the correct states on the html tags.

Comment: The items(pets) itself is a separate model related to multiple objects of the cart, can't store one state : added/not added, for all the users.